# Does the existence of an $\alpha$-approximation scheme for a problem $f$ imply there exists a fully polynomial (deterministic) approximation scheme?

Tags: algorithms, approximation, counting

If you have an $\alpha$-approximation algorithm $A$ for some problem $f \in \#P$, such that (for $0 < \alpha \leq 1$)
$$
\alpha f(x) \leq A(x) \leq \frac{f(x)}{\alpha},
$$
does that automatically imply that you can reduce that accuracy range and have a fully polynomial approximation scheme, $B$, such that (for $\varepsilon > 0$)
$$
(1 - \varepsilon)f(x) \leq B(x) \leq (1 + \varepsilon)f(x)
$$

I'm not really sure what would be the best way to prove or disprove this. One thought would be to show that this property is true for $\#SAT$ and then showing that all problems in $\#P$ reduce to #SAT and thus would have the same property? Although I'm also not sure how to go about proving this for $\#SAT$? Would appreciate any insight!

EDIT: made sure that $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon$ are both strictly greater than zero.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried to disprove it?

Comment: This certainly works for some problems, for example $\#SAT$.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow $\alpha = 0$ and $\epsilon = 0$?